# ¿Cómo llamar a un modal en un else usando laravel?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente input de busqueda:

```
<form id="cliente" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('resultados_clientes')}}" method="get">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label" for="cliente"></label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input form="cliente" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="cliente" type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Introduzca el rif o nombre del cliente a buscar" required>
            <br>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <button form="cliente" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">
              Buscar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Quisiera que al buscar algo que no se encuentre en la base de datos se muestre un error diciendo que el registro no existe

Esta es mi función que uso para buscar

```
public function resultados_clientes(Request $request){
  $busqueda = $request->cliente;
  $clientes = strtoupper($busqueda);
  $perimetro = DB::table('tbl_perimetros as a')
    ->select('a.id','a.rif','a.cod_cliente','a.razon_social','a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_holdings as b','b.id','=','a.holdings_id')
    ->select(array('a.id','b.hrif','b.hrazon_social','a.rif','a.razon_social','a.estatus'))
    ->where('a.rif','like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('a.razon_social', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('b.hrif', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('b.hrazon_social', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')  
    ->get();

  if($perimetro->count()) {

    return view('Busqueda_est.resultados_clientes',compact('perimetro','busqueda'));
  }

    //AQUÍ DEBERÍA IR EL MODAL

    return view('Busqueda_est.index');
}
```

He puesto un comentario para indicar donde qusiera que apareciera el modal o el mensaje de "registro no encontrado":

Este es el modal que quisiera que apareciera al no encontrar alguna busqueda:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h3><center>Mensaje del Sistema</center></h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <h4><center>¡Aviso!</center></h4>
          <center>Cliente no encontrado!!!</center>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Continuar</a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese modal debería encontrarse en la plantilla blade de tu página. Desde el controller deberías mandar un código de error, por ejemplo:

```
$error_code = 1;
return view('Busqueda_est.resultados_clientes', compact('perimetro', 'busqueda', 'error_code'));
```

Luego en la plantilla blade deberías controlar si existe ese error o algún otro tipo de código de error, de ser así lanzarías mediante javascript el modal que necesites:

```
@if(!empty($error_code) && $error_code == 1)
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endif
```

Así debería funcionar sin problemas lo que necesitas.

Comment: muchas gracias ... me ha funcionado!!!!!